# memory read error in my DriverUnload callback,which causes BSOD,why?

Tags: windows, device-driver

I'm following [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/loopback.aspx?display=Print).

Code in `DriverEntry`:

```
UNICODE_STRING symLinkName;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&symLinkName,L"\\??\\HelloDDK");
pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName = symLinkName;
```

Code in `DriverUnload`:

```
VOID HelloDDKUnload (IN PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject) 
{
    PDEVICE_OBJECT  pNextObj;
    KdPrint(("Enter DriverUnload\n"));
    pNextObj = pDriverObject->DeviceObject;
    while (pNextObj != NULL) 
    {
        PDEVICE_EXTENSION pDevExt = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)
            pNextObj->DeviceExtension;
```

Output in windbg:

```
kd> ?? pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName
struct _UNICODE_STRING
 "--- memory read error at address 0xf89f7210 ---"
   +0x000 Length           : 0x18
   +0x002 MaximumLength    : 0x1a
   +0x004 Buffer           : 0xf89f7210  "--- memory read error at address 0xf89f7210 ---"
```

Anyone ever met this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing in DriverUnload, pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName points to a local variable belong to DriverEntry?

Comment: `L"\\??\\HelloDDK"` is restored at a global space.

Answer (score 0):

At the time `DriverUnload` is called there're no more created devices. Hence - it's obsolete to try to use `DeviceObject` and `NextDevice` members of the `DRIVER_OBJECT` structure.

What's surprising is that `NextDevice` isn't set to `NULL`, according to your debug output, but nevertheless it's just a technical note.

If you want to do a per-device cleanup you should rather do it in your dispatch routine in response to `IRP_MJ_CLOSE`.

**UPD**

The question author posted in the comments that iterating through the created devices in the driver unload routine is a common practice, and provided the reference article at the codeproject, with the appropriate source code.

After reading the article and the source code it became more clear.

Usually the driver "creates a device" (i.e. calls `IoCreateDevice`) in response to the OS request, which originates from a call to `CreateFile` (or similar). When the device handle is closed - driver receives the appropriate request and "destroys" the device (`IoDeleteDevice`). The OS will not unload the driver if there're open handles to its devices, hence within the driver uninitialization routine there are no created devices.

However the driver in the reference article doesn't follow this logic. It creates the device at the beginning, right in its initialization routine `DriverEntry`. This does not prevent the OS from unloading the driver, because there're no open references to this device, hence the driver really needs to do the device cleanup in its `DriverUnload`.

Alright, this makes sense now. Except, from my personal experience, it's **not** a common practice to work this way, but this is not forbidden nevertheless.

Now, regarding your problem. Maybe you just made a mistake in the loop? I mean:

```
while (pNextObj != NULL) {
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION pDevExt = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION) pNextObj->DeviceExtension;

    // ...

    pNextObj = pNextObj->NextDevice;

    // then delete the device using the Extension
    IoDeleteDevice( pDevExt->pDevice );
}
```

Are you sure you do the things in the same order? Means, you first get the pointer to the next device object, and then call `IoDeleteDevice`?

Please post the whole code of your `DriverUnload` if you still have the problem.

Comment: @valdo,for NT driver,the device still exists in `DriverUnload`.

Comment: @compile-fan: what makes you think so? AFAIK `DriverUnload` is the driver's global cleanup routine. This is the function to be called last before the driver is finally unloaded. If you were right - this would mean that the driver gets unloaded without being notified about device deleteion - hence without destroying the companion device extension data. This means memory leaks. Also, how would the OS manage the device without the corresponding driver?

Comment: @compile-fan: Also, the system may load the driver, call its `DriverEntry`, then call its `DriverUnload` and then unload it. Without creating the device at all! How would the device "still exist"? I think you confuse between the "device" data and "driver extension" data. The driver extension data definitely should be valid at `DriverUnload`. Because it's a global data, allocated at `DriverEntry`, as opposed to per-device extension data, allocated in `AddDevice` routine.

Comment: @valdo,but why `pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName` doesn't get what's set in `DriverEntry`?

Comment: @compile-fan: `pDevExt' was obtained by a cast from `DriverObject->NextDevice`. Which is invalid.

Comment: @valdo,it's casted from `->DeviceExtension`,not `->NextDevice`.

Comment: @compile-fan: yes, you're right. I mean, `pDevExt` was cast from the `DeviceExtension` member of the struct pointed by `pNextObj`. The latter isn't clear what (I guess `DriverObject->NextDevice`), but this is irrelevant. <b>There are not devices!</b> Hence - there are also no device extensions or whats-or-ever.

Comment: @valdo,I've provided more details as how `pNextObj` comes:)

Comment: It's quite ordinary operation according to this article,but why it doesn't work? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/loopback.aspx?display=Print

Comment: @valdo,things are already wrong when `?? pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName` returns `memory read error at address 0xf89f7210`

Comment: yes, but does this happen on the first loop iteration? (actually you don't need a loop at all since you always create exactly 1 device)

Comment: @valdo,does that example work for you?I tried it on my own computer and is getting the same problem,on the first loop iteration.